# when i use sum and count in single query i get incorrect result

Tags: mysql

for following query:

```
select sum(j.credits) as credits, count(id.redo) as redos 
from operator o inner join jobdetails j on j.opid=o.id 
                inner join imagedetails id on id.opid=o.id 
                and im.redo=y group by o.id
```

Comment: You are doing a group by but the field you are grouping y is not in the select statement?

Comment: @rob it's mysql. You can pretty much do what you like, including this, and even having non aggregated columns not grouped by

Comment: What does that even mean, though? if the grouped item is not in the select, I would assume the aggregate would contain all IDs, and hence, what's the point of the group by? If you wanted to see totals for each id, you would need it to be in the select.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate SUM and COUNT from different table as soon if you have 3 records in `J` and 4 records in `ID` you get 3*4=12 records after JOIN in the result set so you get wrong sum and count. For example:

```
select o.id, j.sum_credits as credits, id.count_redo as redos 
from operator o 
    inner join 
       (select opid, sum(credits) sum_credits from jobdetails group by opid) j 
               on j.opid=o.id 
    inner join 
        (select opid, count(redo) count_redo from imagedetails 
                                              where redo=y group by opid) id 
               on id.opid=o.id
```